# How do I identify xy location on image for overlay

Tags: leaflet, markers

What is the best way to locate the xy points? I could keep guessing and see where the marker moves but that seems inefficient...

I am using leaflet and imageOverlay

```
var sol      = xy(175.2, 145.0);
var mizar    = xy( 41.6, 130.1);
var kruegerZ = xy( 13.4,  56.5);
var deneb    = xy(218.7,   8.3);

L.marker(     sol).addTo(map).bindPopup(      'Test 1');
L.marker(   mizar).addTo(map).bindPopup(    'Test 2');
L.marker(kruegerZ).addTo(map).bindPopup('Test 3');
L.marker(   deneb).addTo(map).bindPopup(    'Test 4');

var travel = L.polyline([sol, deneb]).addTo(map);
```

Comment: You seem to have copy-pasted a few lines from https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html , but because of the way the question is written, it's difficult to understand what you want. Please take the time to read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mean, the maps from that Leaflet tutorial are taken from Ur-Quan Masters, which is a reboot of Star Control 2, for which there are lists of star systems with their in-game coordinates, e.g. https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/3do/584500-star-control-ii/faqs/31697 - therefore "the best way to locate the xy points" *for that particular data set* is to copy-paste. But what is your data set? Where does your map data come from? Maybe we're dealing with a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: Well like the example, there are specific coordinate the tooltip is defined at. I have a blueprint, and what is the easiest way to know its blueprint location, say where a rib is or something like that...

Comment: That depends on the coordinate system you're using for the blueprint. What's it? Please edit your question to include that information. A sample of how the blueprint looks like should help.